# extracting data from espn using python on the tag data-reactid

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am looking to scrape some data from an espn site using python.

http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/playerstats?gameId=293905&league=289234

I am using beautiful soup to extract the content from the page.

```
 item = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'data-reactid': '136'})[0].text
```

Will only show me the column heading. Inside that link are data-reactid links that are not shown in the urls. How does one navigate data-react links ? The url stays the same when you click on defending or attacking link ?

Comment: you will need browser automation e.g. selenium if you are planning on interacting with page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beautifulsoup` path looks difficult. I think this may work for you:

```
import requests
import json
import re

url = "http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/playerstats?gameId=293905&league=289234"
html_doc = requests.get(url)
# not the best regex but it works. there's a lot of data.
stats = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__INITIAL_STATE__\s*=\s*({.*});",html_doc.text).group(1))

# show what we have
stats['gamePackage']['matchLineUp'].keys()                                                                                     
# Out[42]: dict_keys(['text', 'home', 'away', 'gameState', 'sport', 'show'])

# no idea what this sport is. a typo?
stats['gamePackage']['matchLineUp']['sport']                                                                                        
# Out[43]: 'rugby'

stats['gamePackage']['matchLineUp']['home']                                                                                        
# {'name': 'ITALY',
#  'logo': 'http://a1.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/rugby/teams/500/20.png&h=35&w=35',
#  'team': [
#   {'id': '91554',
#    'url': 'http://en.espn.co.uk/sport/rugby/player/91554.html',
#    'name': 'Jayden Hayward',
#    'number': '15',
#    'position': 'FB',
#    'captain': False,
#    'subbed': False,
#    'homeAway': 'home',
#    ...
```

And you can iterate, or whatever:

```
for home_player in stats['gamePackage']['matchLineUp']['home']['team']: 
   print("{} - {}".format(home_player['name'], home_player['number'])) 
Jayden Hayward - 15
Tommaso Benvenuti - 14
Michele Campagnaro - 13
Tommaso Castello - 12
Luca Sperandio - 11
Tommaso Allan - 10
Tito Tebaldi - 9
Andrea Lovotti - 1
Leonardo Ghiraldini - 2
Simone Ferrari - 3
Alessandro Zanni - 4
Dean Budd - 5
Sebastian Negri - 6
Jake Polledri - 7
Braam Steyn - 8
```

There's tons of other info in there but figured this would get you going...

Comment: the reason you are not seeing 136 is because you are looking for 'a' when you do a search rather than span. The issue is loading the content from the page.

Comment: so in the example above, how would you be able to extract the row in the table that has J Haywards attacking stats, and the link that shows his defensive ones. They are all generated by making the data-reactid call.

Comment: Ah - now I'm seeing what you are after. I didn't realize that the "Scoring", "Attacking", ... were "column" headers that load new data, and you want to be able to recover all the columns of data for each player under each category...